# How to delete cookie when the page url is changed but not at time of refreshing in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I want to delete the cookie if my url is changed, as if i don;t do this some of the functionalities are not working properly. Like I want whenever my page reloads means it is opening first then my dropdown should have the value of default. I can do that easily but the main problem occurs when I changed the value of my dropdown i also want that time it should have the last selected option on the dropdown list. I only want the default value when my page is first opened or i change the page then I get back to my dropdown page url.

this is my cookie codes :

```
// create cookie
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
}
//delete cookie
function deleteCookie(name) {
     setCookie(name,"",-1);
 }
```

now I tried to unset my cookie in this way :

```
if(getCookie("myCookie") !== null && getCookie("myCookie") !== ""){
      $('#formA').val(getCookie("myCookie")).trigger('change');
 }
  else {
      goToDefault(); // this onload has the default value "Teacher"
}

    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
         setCookie("myCookie", $('#formA').val(), 12);
    });

   $(window).on('unload', function() {
        if(window.location.pathname !== '/dropdown'){
             deleteCookie("myCookie");   
   }
});
```

i tried under to use this function on`$(window).on('beforeunload'` but in vain. It always works whenver I submit something or page reloads. All I want is this behavior:

this is my dropdown:

Teacher => deafult value option

Student

Books

these are the option of my dropdwon, now if i select `Student` and then work on this option, my dropdown should have it's value as Student only that time untill I change it. But if I change the page, and then again enter on that page I should get default value `Teacher`. 
How should I resolve this?

Comment: Try window.onpopstate

Comment: how to use that and where? @Ameer

Comment: Your actionable task is to remove the value from cookies only if url changes ?

Comment: `window.onpopstate = () => { //remove your cookie here } `, I'll make a full answer based off this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.onpopstate` to detect changes in the url then delete your cookie. Here's an example below:

```
// create cookie
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
}
//delete cookie
function deleteCookie(name) {
     setCookie(name,"",-1);
 }

if(getCookie("myCookie") !== null && getCookie("myCookie") !== ""){
      $('#formA').val(getCookie("myCookie")).trigger('change');
 }
  else {
      goToDefault(); // this onload has the default value "Teacher"
}

    window.onpopstate = () => {
         deleteCookie("myCookie");
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks anyways, the cookie gets cleared but the problem if this `onpopstate` wroks only in the js files of other url page. But I have several page I can't just write this same thing again again. I want if I trigger the js page of my dropdown page, then after I left that place my cookie should be cleared

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but I suppose this is a form you can submit and you want to:

- get the default dropdown option if the page is opened for the first time or in a new page/tab of the browser
- persist the selected option if the page is reloaded
- reset the dropdown to the default option when you submit the form (and therefore probably change URL)

What you may want to look into is [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) which similarly to `cookies` and `localStorage` allows you to save some data (in different ways).

Saving data to `sessionStorage` is as simple as:

```js
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

What's important is that this could be the perfect solution for your problem because out of the box `sessionStorage` will clear the data you saved when the *page session ends*. As per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) (which I encourage you to check)

> a page session lasts as long as the browser is open, and survives over page reloads and restores

---

To answer your question, you probably can:

- save the selected option with `sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value')` when it changes
- use `sessionStorage.getItem('key')` to retrieve the value of the dropdown
- use `sessionStorage.removeItem('key')` to remove the saved key when you submit the form

A new page or tab won't find any saved option cause the *session* will be a completely new one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did I understand your problem correctly? After you try this solution, let the community know if the answer was useful to you problem by marking the answer as the correct one